# Can't save projects. How to change 'read-only' status?

Tags: windows, phpstorm, file-permissions

PHPStorm thinks that my main folder, where my projects are, has "read-only" status. It says "could not save project".

The way it started was that I used a command line tool, it may have been cygwin(a linux based command line tool), or cmd or windows powershell, following a tutorial which was mac oriented. It showed how you could change permissions on folders. It was some time ago and I don't have the tutorial anymore. I don't remember the commands I made, but I only changed permissions on my project folder just to try it out.

I have then changed the permissions back on the folder so that both administrator and normal users have full access to it. But I did it by right clicking the folder and go to "security". PHPStorm still displays the read-only message and can't save the project.

I would greatly appreciate a solution!

Comment: Did you try restarting both the IDE and your machine? Did you check Unlocker to see if the files are locked? Are the files downloaded from somewhere, and marked unsafe by Windows? Did it suddenly stop working, or has saving this project never worked?

Comment: I just updated my post with some info on my initial changes. I didn't know that changing permissions back and forth could end up with losing data...

Comment: Changing permissions would not normally result in a loss of content, but you should consider using source control and backups anyway.  Can you please paste your security permissions dialogue box and someone can probably help.